# Marker not showing in legend after changing labels (seaborn and matplotlib)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, legend

When I change the legend titles, only the first of my two markers is redrawn, am I doing something wrong, or is there a workaround?

I ran the code below:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

#create dataframe
np.random.seed(seed=10)

x = np.arange(0,20)
y1 = np.arange(0,20) + 10*np.random.rand(20)
y2 = np.arange(20,0,-1) + 10*np.random.rand(20)
mask = np.random.randint(low=0, high=2, size=20, dtype=bool)

df = pd.DataFrame()

df['x'] = x
df['y1'] = y1
df['y2'] = y2
df['mask'] = mask

#plot results
fig, axs = plt.subplots(2)

f1 = sns.scatterplot(data=df, y='y1', x='x', ax=axs[0], hue="mask")
f2 = sns.scatterplot(data=df, y='y2', x='x', ax=axs[1], hue="mask")

new_title = ""
new_labels = ['Include', 'Exclude']

for ax in axs:
    ax.legend(title=new_title, labels=new_labels)
    
fig.savefig(r"C:\\Temp\error.png", bbox="tight")
```

The result is below. As you can see the "Include" label in the legend has a marker, but the "Exclude" label does not

[image]

Comment: Your problem isn't reproducible.  Could you add some test data for the dataframe?  Are you using recent matplotlib and seaborn versions?

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, have updated the post based on it. All packages are the most recent version available through pip

Comment: Thank you for the reproducible code.  When I try it, I also get a blue dot in the legend.  Maybe there is some problem with `dtype=bool`, you might try converting them to `int`.  The way seaborn works best, would be to replace the bools by strings: `df = df.replace({'mask': {True: 'Include', False:'Exclude'}})`, which would directly create the correct legend labels.  To change the title, in seaborn 0.11.2 there is a new function `sns.move_legend(ax, title='', loc='best')`

Comment: Not reproducible on my end either. I get dots for both legend entries. `sns.__version__` is 0.11.2 and `matplotlib.__version__` is 3.5.1

Comment: Hi, thanks for looking. I went back and checked and realised I was using an old version of seaborn in the environment I was running this in. Updating from 0.9 to 0.11 fixed the problem